# Import External "Document" File in R Programming

Tags: macos

I am very new in R Programming, my concern is about importing "Document" kind of files. I say "Document" because when I go to "Get Info" and see what type of data it is, this is what I see:

[image]

I know how to open .txt or .csv files, but how about "document" types? Without resorting to exporting this kind of file manually using Excel.

I'm using Mac OS, btw.
Thanks!

Comment: What's the file extension?

Comment: Hello Sir, I added an image. Even after setting Finder to show File extensions, I only see this. No file extension, and the kind of file is "Document"

Comment: @JennEve The "kind" is only based on the extension. Try opening it in the same program that you use to open `SMSSpamCollection.txt`. Look to see if it is plain text that you can read. If so, you will be able to read this file just as you read other `.txt` files into R.

Comment: Where did you get the file? What program do you usually use with it? Can you open the file in a text editor? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: This is not a question that has anything to do with R. You are probably in some IDE, RStudio perhaps, and you are getting a graphical display of what the OS calls any "document' that has no extension... and  this is evidence that you do not understand those systems.

Comment: @nograpes yes, i'm now able to open (without adding a .txt extension in the filename argument). Thanks to all who tried to help me, your comments lead me the way.

Comment: @Dwin, that's why I said I'm very new in R Programming. I just learned it from http://tryr.codeschool.com/ I'm not using RStudio. The screenshot was definitely from Finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the file, just like any other .txt file. Simply because it lacks a proper extension name, does not change much.  (now if it is not a text file, that is another issue altogether, but I would bet it is)

---

Try the following:

```
read.table("~/SMSSpamCollection", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

*Change `"~/"` to the `"ptah/to/your/file/"`*

Mess around with `header`, `sep`, etc.

see `?read.table` for more help